# Maps API for JavaScript in HERE MAP

Tags: javascript

[This is the JS file i have included](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yulc.jpg)I started using HERE MAP javascript to simply display a map based on latitude and longitude coordinates. I get a javascript ReferenceError on the very first line!

code snippet:

```
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
        'app_id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'app_code': 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz'
    });
    // Obtain the default map types from the platform object
var maptypes = platform.createDefaultLayers();
    // Instantiate (and display) a map object:
var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('bodydiv'), maptypes.normal.map, {
        zoom: 10, center: { lng: <%=longitude%>, lat: <%=latitude%>}
    });
```

ReferenceError: H is not defined - happens on var platform=...

Could you please me out..I have included the JS files also

Comment: Did you include the HERE API before your script?

Comment: can you please include entire file where you are using it?

Answer (score 0):

Include the following lines BEFORE you start using the HERE API. It seems, you are using the API without importing it

```
<script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js"
  type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js"
  type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

var platform = new H.service.Platform({
'app_id': 'GphmMpss5NBDYQNhsSr173',
'app_code': 'mbQsgfdweiqdzxTbHTZbe0pg'
});
```

Comment: it can also happen if you add `defer` attribute to script tag

Comment: Yep that is true!

Comment: In my platform where i am working i need to add this JS file in JS Tab.and the JS code in JS widget. and taking another HTML to display the map..But its shows me the H is not defined..I have already included the "http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js" and "http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js" in my Platform JS file. but still iam facing the issue. Please help

Comment: Can you confirm that in the browser DOM, these src tags are placed before your custom code?

Comment: I have edited my first question and added my screenshot please refer and let me know.

Comment: Screenshot gives no way to determine the issue. Inspect element, this will give you way to look at the DOM. In the DOM check where is the HERE JS placed as compared to your custom code. Ideally, it should be before

Comment: when i use  the whole HTML which is shared in below URL then also i am unable to see the map --  https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/quick-start.html

Comment: strange. i am assuming you have the app id and key from the site. right?

Comment: Yes i have applied the app_code and app id for javascript/rest

Comment: i just tried at my end and it worked perfectly. I copied their entire HTML and just replaced with my app id and key.

Comment: yes..Thanks.. it worked now..when i use the js file as //js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js without using anuy HTTP ..Thanks